# Task using httpclient and returning a value not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, task

I've looked around and followed a few tutorials on how to set this up and I'm having no luck. I'm building a cross platform app using Xamarin. I have a portable class library to handle all my business logic and web service calls.

The issue I'm having is when I run the code within the method below it works without an issue however if I run it as shown below as a task it takes a long time. I believe its deadlocked but as I'm new to this I can't understand why. I want my Api calls to be in the PCL so I can share it between each platfrom.

```
public async Task<LoginResponse> Login(string userName, string password)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string baseUrl = "http://someURLhere/";

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

    string authData = string.Format("/IOSLogin?Username={0}&Password={1}&languageSettingOnDevice={2}", userName, password, "en");

    var uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}", baseUrl, authData));

    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

       LoginResponse jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(content);
       jsonResponse.loginSuccesfull = true;
       return jsonResponse;
    }
    else
    {
       return new LoginResponse() { loginSuccesfull = false };
    }
}
```

In the project for the ios version, on a button event I use this code to run the task shown above.

```
Core.Service.AtmisService service = new Core.Service.AtmisService();
LoginResponse loginTask = service.Login(userName.Text, password.Text).Result;
```

I thought that by setting it up this way when I use `.Result` at the end of call to the task it would execute this task and return the result. I have added breakpoints and it enters the login method and gets as far as this `var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);` and then it simply does nothing. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing this article [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

> “Async all the way” means that you shouldn’t mix synchronous and
>   asynchronous code without carefully considering the consequences. In
>   particular, it’s usually a bad idea to block on async code by calling
>   Task.Wait or Task.Result. This is an especially common problem for
>   programmers who are “dipping their toes” into asynchronous
>   programming, converting just a small part of their application and
>   wrapping it in a synchronous API so the rest of the application is
>   isolated from the changes. Unfortunately, they run into problems with
>   deadlocks. After answering many async-related questions on the MSDN
>   forums, Stack Overflow and e-mail, I can say this is by far the
>   most-asked question by async newcomers once they learn the basics:
>   “Why does my partially async code deadlock?”

Don’t mix blocking and async code. You should go Async all the way. Your deadlock is because the `.Result` is blocking.

you want to do...

```
LoginResponse loginTask = await service.Login(userName.Text, password.Text);
```

> To summarize this second guideline, you should avoid mixing async and
>   blocking code. Mixed async and blocking code can cause deadlocks,
>   more-complex error handling and unexpected blocking of context
>   threads. The exception to this guideline is the Main method for
>   console applications, or—if you’re an advanced user—managing a
>   partially asynchronous codebase.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

In Your case using a button EventHandler you would do something like this:

```
private async void myButtonItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Core.Service.AtmisService service = new Core.Service.AtmisService();
            LoginResponse loginTask = await service.Login(userName.Text, password.Text).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //The rest of the code in this method may run in a different thread than the one that invoked the method. If you have ui code after this then avoid using ConfigureAwait(false)
        }
```

You can find more information on avoiding deadlocks [here](https://blog.ciber.no/2014/05/19/using-task-configureawaitfalse-to-prevent-deadlocks-in-async-code/).